openapi quarkus - missing equals and hashCode in generated methods
I use this library on Quarkus https://docs.quarkiverse.io/quarkus-openapi-generator/dev/client.html
My class generated by the open api plugin doesnt have "hashCode" and "equals" methods but "toString" only..
I want to know how i can find the right template to copy to my resources directory for adding these methods by myself (using qute syntax) or are there other more fast alternative, please?
I need to make it using only a subset of fields in the comparation.
Let me know. The documentation link https://github.com/quarkiverse/quarkus-openapi-generator/tree/main/integration-tests/custom-templates doesn't work.
This is my dependencies and pom configurations:
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkiverse.openapi.generator</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-openapi-generator</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
   <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-openapi</artifactId>
</dependency>

   <plugin>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.9</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>build</goal>
          <goal>generate-code</goal>
          <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>

This is one pojo class generated without hashcode and equals:
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeName;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonValue;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class DocumentDtoOutput  {

    private String uuid;
    private Long version = 1l;
    private String externalId;
    private String description;
    private String contentBase64;
    private String documentGroup;
    private String mimeType;
    private Map<String, String> filenetIndexes;
    private Map<String, String> longTermStoragIndex;
    private String filenetDocumentClass;
    private Boolean isToSign;
    private Boolean isMandatory;
    private Boolean isBankToSign;

    public enum CopyTypeEnum {
        COPIA_CLIENTE(String.valueOf("COPIA_CLIENTE")), COPIA_BANCA(String.valueOf("COPIA_BANCA")), EMPTY(String.valueOf(""));

   -............ (some others code here)

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     **/
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public DocumentDtoOutput description(String description) {
        this.description = description;
        return this;
    }

    /**
    * File content in base64 string
    * @return contentBase64
    **/
    @JsonProperty("contentBase64")
          @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude(com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    public String getContentBase64() {
        return contentBase64;
    }

    /**
     * Set contentBase64
     **/
    public void setContentBase64(String contentBase64) {
        this.contentBase64 = contentBase64;
    }

    public DocumentDtoOutput contentBase64(String contentBase64) {
        this.contentBase64 = contentBase64;
        return this;
    }

    /**
    * Document group
    * @return documentGroup
    **/
    @JsonProperty("documentGroup")
          @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude(com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    public String getDocumentGroup() {
        return documentGroup;
    }

    /**
     * Set documentGroup
     **/
    public void setDocumentGroup(String documentGroup) {
        this.documentGroup = documentGroup;
    }

    public DocumentDtoOutput documentGroup(String documentGroup) {
        this.documentGroup = documentGroup;
        return this;
    }

    /**
    * Document mimeType
    * @return mimeType
    **/
    @JsonProperty("mimeType")
          @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude(com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    public String getMimeType() {
        return mimeType;
    }

    /**
     * Set mimeType
     **/
    public void setMimeType(String mimeType) {
        this.mimeType = mimeType;
    }

    public DocumentDtoOutput mimeType(String mimeType) {
        this.mimeType = mimeType;
        return this;
    }

    /**
    * map of filenet indexes
    * @return filenetIndexes
    **/
    @JsonProperty("filenetIndexes")
          @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude(com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    public Map<String, String> getFilenetIndexes() {
        return filenetIndexes;
    }

    /**
     * Set filenetIndexes
     **/
    public void setFilenetIndexes(Map<String, String> filenetIndexes) {
        this.filenetIndexes = filenetIndexes;
    }

    public DocumentDtoOutput filenetIndexes(Map<String, String> filenetIndexes) {
        this.filenetIndexes = filenetIndexes;
        return this;
    }
    public DocumentDtoOutput putFilenetIndexesItem(String key, String filenetIndexesItem) {
           if (this.filenetIndexes == null){
                filenetIndexes = new HashMap<>();
            }
        this.filenetIndexes.put(key, filenetIndexesItem);
        return this;
    }

    /**
    * map of long term storage indexes
    * @return longTermStoragIndex
    **/
    @JsonProperty("longTermStoragIndex")
          @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude(com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    public Map<String, String> getLongTermStoragIndex() {
        return longTermStoragIndex;
    }

    /**
     * Set longTermStoragIndex
     **/
    public void setLongTermStoragIndex(Map<String, String> longTermStoragIndex) {
        this.longTermStoragIndex = longTermStoragIndex;
    }

    public DocumentDtoOutput longTermStoragIndex(Map<String, String> longTermStoragIndex) {
        this.longTermStoragIndex = longTermStoragIndex;
        return this;
    }
    public DocumentDtoOutput putLongTermStoragIndexItem(String key, String longTermStoragIndexItem) {
           if (this.longTermStoragIndex == null){
                longTermStoragIndex = new HashMap<>();
            }
        this.longTermStoragIndex.put(key, longTermStoragIndexItem);
        return this;
    }

    /**
    * Filenet document class
    * @return filenetDocumentClass
    **/
    @JsonProperty("filenetDocumentClass")
    public String getFilenetDocumentClass() {
        return filenetDocumentClass;
    }

    /**
     * Set filenetDocumentClass
     **/
    public void setFilenetDocumentClass(String filenetDocumentClass) {
        this.filenetDocumentClass = filenetDocumentClass;
    }

    public DocumentDtoOutput filenetDocumentClass(String filenetDocumentClass) {
        this.filenetDocumentClass = filenetDocumentClass;
        return this;
    }

    /**
    * Specify if document must be signed
    * @return isToSign
    **/
    @JsonProperty("isToSign")
    public Boolean getIsToSign() {
        return isToSign;
    }

    /**
     * Set isToSign
     **/
    public void setIsToSign(Boolean isToSign) {
        this.isToSign = isToSign;
    }

    public DocumentDtoOutput isToSign(Boolean isToSign) {
        this.isToSign = isToSign;
        return this;
    }

    /**
    * Specify if acknowledgment is mandatory
    * @return isMandatory
    **/
    @JsonProperty("isMandatory")
    public Boolean getIsMandatory() {
        return isMandatory;
    }

    /**
     * Set isMandatory
     **/
    public void setIsMandatory(Boolean isMandatory) {
        this.isMandatory = isMandatory;
    }

    public DocumentDtoOutput isMandatory(Boolean isMandatory) {
        this.isMandatory = isMandatory;
        return this;
    }

    /**
    * presa visione is completed
    * @return isBankToSign
    **/
    @JsonProperty("isBankToSign")
    public Boolean getIsBankToSign() {
        return isBankToSign;
    }

    /**
     * Set isBankToSign
     **/
    public void setIsBankToSign(Boolean isBankToSign) {
        this.isBankToSign = isBankToSign;
    }

    public DocumentDtoOutput isBankToSign(Boolean isBankToSign) {
        this.isBankToSign = isBankToSign;
        return this;
    }

    /**
    * COPIA_CLIENTE or COPIA_BANCA or leave empty(no mandatory field)
    * @return copyType
    **/
    @JsonProperty("copyType")
          @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude(com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    public CopyTypeEnum getCopyType() {
        return copyType;
    }

    /**
     * Set copyType
     **/
    public void setCopyType(CopyTypeEnum copyType) {
        this.copyType = copyType;
    }

    public DocumentDtoOutput copyType(CopyTypeEnum copyType) {
        this.copyType = copyType;
        return this;
    }

    /**
    * File name
    * @return fileName
    **/
    @JsonProperty("fileName")
          @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude(com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    /**
     * Set fileName
     **/
    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public DocumentDtoOutput fileName(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Create a string representation of this pojo.
     **/
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("class DocumentDtoOutput {\n");

        sb.append("    uuid: ").append(toIndentedString(uuid)).append("\n");
        sb.append("    version: ").append(toIndentedString(version)).append("\n");
        sb.append("    externalId: ").append(toIndentedString(externalId)).append("\n");
        sb.append("    description: ").append(toIndentedString(description)).append("\n");
        sb.append("    contentBase64: ").append(toIndentedString(contentBase64)).append("\n");
        sb.append("    documentGroup: ").append(toIndentedString(documentGroup)).append("\n");
        sb.append("    mimeType: ").append(toIndentedString(mimeType)).append("\n");
        sb.append("    filenetIndexes: ").append(toIndentedString(filenetIndexes)).append("\n");
        sb.append("    longTermStoragIndex: ").append(toIndentedString(longTermStoragIndex)).append("\n");
        sb.append("    filenetDocumentClass: ").append(toIndentedString(filenetDocumentClass)).append("\n");
        sb.append("    isToSign: ").append(toIndentedString(isToSign)).append("\n");
        sb.append("    isMandatory: ").append(toIndentedString(isMandatory)).append("\n");
        sb.append("    isBankToSign: ").append(toIndentedString(isBankToSign)).append("\n");
        sb.append("    copyType: ").append(toIndentedString(copyType)).append("\n");
        sb.append("    fileName: ").append(toIndentedString(fileName)).append("\n");
        
        sb.append("}");
        return sb.toString();
    }

    /**
     * Convert the given object to string with each line indented by 4 spaces
     * (except the first line).
     */
    private static String toIndentedString(Object o) {
        if (o == null) {
            return "null";
        }
        return o.toString().replace("\n", "\n    ");
    }

    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public static class DocumentDtoOutputQueryParam  {

        @jakarta.ws.rs.QueryParam("uuid")
        private String uuid;
        @jakarta.ws.rs.QueryParam("version")
        private Long version = 1l;
        @jakarta.ws.rs.QueryParam("externalId")
        private String externalId;
        @jakarta.ws.rs.QueryParam("description")
        private String description;
        @jakarta.ws.rs.QueryParam("contentBase64")
        private String contentBase64;
        @jakarta.ws.rs.QueryParam("documentGroup")
        private String documentGroup;
        @jakarta.ws.rs.QueryParam("mimeType")
        private String mimeType;
        @jakarta.ws.rs.QueryParam("filenetIndexes")
        private Map<String, String> filenetIndexes = null;
        @jakarta.ws.rs.QueryParam("longTermStoragIndex")
        private Map<String, String> longTermStoragIndex = null;
        @jakarta.ws.rs.QueryParam("filenetDocumentClass")
        private String filenetDocumentClass;
        @jakarta.ws.rs.QueryParam("isToSign")
        private Boolean isToSign;
        @jakarta.ws.rs.QueryParam("isMandatory")
        private Boolean isMandatory;
        @jakarta.ws.rs.QueryParam("isBankToSign")
        private Boolean isBankToSign;

    public enum CopyTypeEnum {
        COPIA_CLIENTE(String.valueOf("COPIA_CLIENTE")), COPIA_BANCA(String.valueOf("COPIA_BANCA")), EMPTY(String.valueOf(""));

        // caching enum access
        private static final java.util.EnumSet<CopyTypeEnum> values = java.util.EnumSet.allOf(CopyTypeEnum.class);

        String value;

        CopyTypeEnum (String v) {
            value = v;
        }

        @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonValue
        public String value() {
            return value;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.valueOf(value);
        }

        @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator
        public static CopyTypeEnum fromString(String v) {
            for (CopyTypeEnum b : values) {
                if (String.valueOf(b.value).equalsIgnoreCase(v)) {
                    return b;
                }
            }
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected value '" + v + "'");
        }
    }
        private CopyTypeEnum copyType;
        @jakarta.ws.rs.QueryParam("fileName")
        private String fileName;

        /**
        * Unique identifier 36 chars lenght(UUID)
        * @return uuid
        **/
        @JsonProperty("uuid")
        public String getUuid() {
            return uuid;
        }

        /**
         * Set uuid
         **/
        public void setUuid(String uuid) {
            this.uuid = uuid;
        }

        public DocumentDtoOutputQueryParam uuid(String uuid) {
            this.uuid = uuid;
            return this;
        }

        /**
        * Jpa version for optimistic lock, pass the right value of an existing signer, otherwise pass 1
        * @return version
        **/
        @JsonProperty("version")
        public Long getVersion() {
            return version;
        }

        /**
         * Set version
         **/
        public void setVersion(Long version) {
            this.version = version;
        }

        public DocumentDtoOutputQueryParam version(Long version) {
            this.version = version;
            return this;
        }

        /**
        * Application external id (useful to retrieve document without use the generated id)
        * @return externalId
        **/
        @JsonProperty("externalId")
        public String getExternalId() {
            return externalId;
        }

        /**
         * Set externalId
         **/
        public void setExternalId(String externalId) {
            this.externalId = externalId;
        }

        public DocumentDtoOutputQueryParam externalId(String externalId) {
            this.externalId = externalId;
            return this;
        }

        /**
        * Document description
        * @return description
        **/
        @JsonProperty("description")
        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        /**
         * Set description
         **/
        public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }

        public DocumentDtoOutputQueryParam description(String description) {
            this.description = description;
            return this;
        }

        /**
        * File content in base64 string
        * @return contentBase64
        **/
        @JsonProperty("contentBase64")
        public String getContentBase64() {
            return contentBase64;
        }

        /**
         * Set contentBase64
         **/
        public void setContentBase64(String contentBase64) {
            this.contentBase64 = contentBase64;
        }

        public DocumentDtoOutputQueryParam contentBase64(String contentBase64) {
            this.contentBase64 = contentBase64;
            return this;
        }

        /**
        * Document group
        * @return documentGroup
        **/
        @JsonProperty("documentGroup")
        public String getDocumentGroup() {
            return documentGroup;
        }

        /**
         * Set documentGroup
         **/
        public void setDocumentGroup(String documentGroup) {
            this.documentGroup = documentGroup;
        }

        public DocumentDtoOutputQueryParam documentGroup(String documentGroup) {
            this.documentGroup = documentGroup;
            return this;
        }

        /**
        * Document mimeType
        * @return mimeType
        **/
        @JsonProperty("mimeType")
        public String getMimeType() {
            return mimeType;
        }

        /**
         * Set mimeType
         **/
        public void setMimeType(String mimeType) {
            this.mimeType = mimeType;
        }

        public DocumentDtoOutputQueryParam mimeType(String mimeType) {
            this.mimeType = mimeType;
            return this;
        }

        /**
        * map of filenet indexes
        * @return filenetIndexes
        **/
        @JsonProperty("filenetIndexes")
        public Map<String, String> getFilenetIndexes() {
            return filenetIndexes;
        }

        /**
         * Set filenetIndexes
         **/
        public void setFilenetIndexes(Map<String, String> filenetIndexes) {
            this.filenetIndexes = filenetIndexes;
        }

        public DocumentDtoOutputQueryParam filenetIndexes(Map<String, String> filenetIndexes) {
            this.filenetIndexes = filenetIndexes;
            return this;
        }
        public DocumentDtoOutputQueryParam putFilenetIndexesItem(String key, String filenetIndexesItem) {
            this.filenetIndexes.put(key, filenetIndexesItem);
            return this;
        }

        /**
        * map of long term storage indexes
        * @return longTermStoragIndex
        **/
        @JsonProperty("longTermStoragIndex")
        public Map<String, String> getLongTermStoragIndex() {
            return longTermStoragIndex;
        }

        /**
         * Set longTermStoragIndex
         **/
        public void setLongTermStoragIndex(Map<String, String> longTermStoragIndex) {
            this.longTermStoragIndex = longTermStoragIndex;
        }

        public DocumentDtoOutputQueryParam longTermStoragIndex(Map<String, String> longTermStoragIndex) {
            this.longTermStoragIndex = longTermStoragIndex;
            return this;
        }
        public DocumentDtoOutputQueryParam putLongTermStoragIndexItem(String key, String longTermStoragIndexItem) {
            this.longTermStoragIndex.put(key, longTermStoragIndexItem);
            return this;
        }

        /**
        * Filenet document class
        * @return filenetDocumentClass
        **/
        @JsonProperty("filenetDocumentClass")
        public String getFilenetDocumentClass() {
            return filenetDocumentClass;
        }

        /**
         * Set filenetDocumentClass
         **/
        public void setFilenetDocumentClass(String filenetDocumentClass) {
            this.filenetDocumentClass = filenetDocumentClass;
        }

        public DocumentDtoOutputQueryParam filenetDocumentClass(String filenetDocumentClass) {
            this.filenetDocumentClass = filenetDocumentClass;
            return this;
        }

        /**
        * Specify if document must be signed
        * @return isToSign
        **/
        @JsonProperty("isToSign")
        public Boolean getIsToSign() {
            return isToSign;
        }

        /**
         * Set isToSign
         **/
        public void setIsToSign(Boolean isToSign) {
            this.isToSign = isToSign;
        }

        public DocumentDtoOutputQueryParam isToSign(Boolean isToSign) {
            this.isToSign = isToSign;
            return this;
        }

        /**
        * Specify if acknowledgment is mandatory
        * @return isMandatory
        **/
        @JsonProperty("isMandatory")
        public Boolean getIsMandatory() {
            return isMandatory;
        }

        /**
         * Set isMandatory
         **/
        public void setIsMandatory(Boolean isMandatory) {
            this.isMandatory = isMandatory;
        }

        public DocumentDtoOutputQueryParam isMandatory(Boolean isMandatory) {
            this.isMandatory = isMandatory;
            return this;
        }

        /**
        * presa visione is completed
        * @return isBankToSign
        **/
        @JsonProperty("isBankToSign")
        public Boolean getIsBankToSign() {
            return isBankToSign;
        }

        /**
         * Set isBankToSign
         **/
        public void setIsBankToSign(Boolean isBankToSign) {
            this.isBankToSign = isBankToSign;
        }

        public DocumentDtoOutputQueryParam isBankToSign(Boolean isBankToSign) {
            this.isBankToSign = isBankToSign;
            return this;
        }

        /**
        * COPIA_CLIENTE or COPIA_BANCA or leave empty(no mandatory field)
        * @return copyType
        **/
        @JsonProperty("copyType")
        public CopyTypeEnum getCopyType() {
            return copyType;
        }

        /**
         * Set copyType
         **/
        public void setCopyType(CopyTypeEnum copyType) {
            this.copyType = copyType;
        }

        public DocumentDtoOutputQueryParam copyType(CopyTypeEnum copyType) {
            this.copyType = copyType;
            return this;
        }

        /**
        * File name
        * @return fileName
        **/
        @JsonProperty("fileName")
        public String getFileName() {
            return fileName;
        }

        /**
         * Set fileName
         **/
        public void setFileName(String fileName) {
            this.fileName = fileName;
        }

        public DocumentDtoOutputQueryParam fileName(String fileName) {
            this.fileName = fileName;
            return this;
        }

        /**
         * Create a string representation of this pojo.
         **/
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("class DocumentDtoOutputQueryParam {\n");

            sb.append("    uuid: ").append(toIndentedString(uuid)).append("\n");
            sb.append("    version: ").append(toIndentedString(version)).append("\n");
            sb.append("    externalId: ").append(toIndentedString(externalId)).append("\n");
            sb.append("    description: ").append(toIndentedString(description)).append("\n");
            sb.append("    contentBase64: ").append(toIndentedString(contentBase64)).append("\n");
            sb.append("    documentGroup: ").append(toIndentedString(documentGroup)).append("\n");
            sb.append("    mimeType: ").append(toIndentedString(mimeType)).append("\n");
            sb.append("    filenetIndexes: ").append(toIndentedString(filenetIndexes)).append("\n");
            sb.append("    longTermStoragIndex: ").append(toIndentedString(longTermStoragIndex)).append("\n");
            sb.append("    filenetDocumentClass: ").append(toIndentedString(filenetDocumentClass)).append("\n");
            sb.append("    isToSign: ").append(toIndentedString(isToSign)).append("\n");
            sb.append("    isMandatory: ").append(toIndentedString(isMandatory)).append("\n");
            sb.append("    isBankToSign: ").append(toIndentedString(isBankToSign)).append("\n");
            sb.append("    copyType: ").append(toIndentedString(copyType)).append("\n");
            sb.append("    fileName: ").append(toIndentedString(fileName)).append("\n");
            sb.append("}");
            return sb.toString();
        }

        /**
         * Convert the given object to string with each line indented by 4 spaces
         * (except the first line).
         */
        private static String toIndentedString(Object o) {
            if (o == null) {
                return "null";
            }
            return o.toString().replace("\n", "\n    ");
        }
    }
}

 


See https://github.com/quarkiverse/quarkus-openapi-generator/blob/main/client/deployment/src/main/resources/templates/libraries/microprofile/pojo.qute for the POJO template. Adding value based equals and hash code there is not trivial, but should be possible. Do you really need them?

You can find that integration test here: https://github.com/quarkiverse/quarkus-openapi-generator/tree/main/client/integration-tests/custom-templates
